# Insert data into exist excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a exist excel file. It has style, ex : table, color,.....(like a below image)so, i want t insert data from datagridview into excel( row 5 and data exsit in a table).My code that works but data don't exist in table and last rows removed.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(filePath);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
app.Visible = true;
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 4, j + 1] = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
app.Quit();
```

[image]

Comment: Save the file xlWorkBook.SaveAs(FilePath + ".xlsx"); before app.Quit();

Comment: @imsome1: Yes, i commented that line.

Comment: Did you debug and see the values of dataGridView3?

Comment: @imsome1 yah, my mean the post above works but data inserted don't exsit in table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
string fileName = "YOUR_EXCEL_FILE";

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 4, j + 1] = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(YOUR_PATH+ ".xlsx");
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
xlWorkSheet = null;
xlWorkBook = null;
xlApp = null;


Process.Start("" + YOUR_PATH + ".xlsx");
```

Comment: it works but i have a problem with format file. I can't insert new rows into exsit table(this table is  format file).